# Vertical icon bar

Tags: wordpress, html, css

HTML

```
<div>
 <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
 <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
 <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a>
 <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
 <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i></a>
 <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a>
<div>
```

CSS

```
.fa {
 padding: 5px;
 font-size: 30px;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 line-height:40px;
 text-align:center;
 position:relative;
 float:right;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 }
.fa a {
 display:block;
 }
```

As it can be seen that these icons are horizontally aligned but i need a vertical icon bar,so is there anything i forgot to add.I'm also attaching a screenshot below. [image] Thanks in advance for solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed .fa class properties

```
.fa {
 padding: 5px;
 font-size: 30px;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 line-height:50px;
 text-align:center;
 }
```

Also right code `a .fa` not `.fa a`

```
a .fa {
 display:block;
 }
a {text-decoration: none;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove float and correct your last selector :

```css
.fa {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background: blue;
  border-bottom:1px solid red; /*not needed, simply to show blocks*/
}

a .fa {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i></a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way (its' working...):-

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
 <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
 <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
 <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a>
 <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
 <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i></a>
 <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a>
<div>


div {
  width:50px;
  height:300px;
  float:right;
}
a {
 padding: 5px;
 font-size: 30px;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 line-height:40px;
 }
```